# Laravel Mix URL processing distorts file path

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, laravel-mix

I'm trying to set up Larvel Mix with internal URL processing, but somehow it disfigures all my file paths.
For instance, if I use an icon in **app.scss**:

```
background-image: url("../icons/search.svg");
```

Everytime I get in app.css

```
background-image: url(/fonts/search.svg?0aeb120951582cc56d9d8681f88ff583);
```

The corresponding file is also copied to public/fonts/ and I just can't figure out, where this folder creeps into my path.
In my webpack.mix.js I don't have anything special.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
```

Has anybody already had this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Laravel-mix will optimize relative stylesheet url()'s by default.

To disable this feature, go to `webpack.mix.js` in your project root.

Add:

```
mix.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});
```

---

However, if your use bootstrap-sass, it will cause it's Glyphicons font can't work.

To fix this, go to `resources\assets\sass\_variables.scss`

Change `$icon-font-path:` to `"../fonts/vendor/._bootstrap-sass@3.3.7@bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/";`

Comment: Thanks, that was also my first idea. But is there some way to rewrite this default setting? I mean, this feature is quite useful, apart from this problem with paths building.

Comment: Thanks solved my problem. How did you find that? Are there any docs or did you go through the code of laravel mix?

Comment: @TecBeast I find it in laravel mix's document. It's a npm package. See [HERE](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/css-preprocessors.md)